How to use cicflowmeter in windows?
I have installed cicflowmeter using this command in vscode:

pip install cicflowmeter

And now I want to convert some pcap files to csv using this cicflowmeter. But this command is showing error:
C:\Users\disha\Downloads\btp code>cicflowmeter -f input.pcap -c flows.csv Exception in thread AsyncSniffer: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\disha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()   File "C:\Users\disha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\disha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 1116, in _run
    sniff_sockets.update((PcapReader(   File "C:\Users\disha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 1118, in <genexpr>
    tcpdump(fname,   File "C:\Users\disha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scapy\utils.py", line 2673, in tcpdump
    raise Scapy_Exception( scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: tcpdump is not available


Can this answer solve your porblem?
